# Grub install error in external HDD

Tags: grub-efi

I'm trying to install ubuntu 20.4 in my external HDD I've done everything said on the internet. I have made partition with gparted with a 4gb swap(I have 4gb ram) 100mb fat32 efi and a ext4 part with 150gb. Still everytime i try to install it shows grub-install dev/sdac error fatal. Then restart option. Can anyone please help

Comment: You must have seen old instructions. New versions of Ubuntu use swap file since 17.10. But swap partition will be used if found. Also ESP - efi system partition is suggested to be 300 to 600MB, but 100 will work if just standard Ubuntu. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I would not put a swap partition on an external HDD.  You don't need a swap partition.  I suggest that you format the disk and let the installer create the partitions for you.  If you want us to evaluate any errors, you need to reproduce the errors in the body of your question verbatim, unredacted, formatted as `monospace` and retaining all line breaks. You should also explain exactly what steps you are taking to reproduce this error.  The more diagnostic information you leave out of your question, the less likely someone will have an answer

Comment: @oldfred & OP: I don't think 100MB is enough for EFI.  I suggest 250GB.  Kernels keep getting bigger.  But if you just let the installer create the partitions for you, then you shouldn't have issues arising from improper partitioning

Comment: Ok then should i delete all the partitions? And then what steps to do can anyone tell

Comment: I deleted all the partitions, just made one ext4 file system with / still same error... I had installed ubuntu earlier by dual booting on my internal hard drive that time there was no issues.. I don't know what's happening with this external one

Comment: [I suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290220/grub-install-error-in-external-hdd#comment2190436_1290220)  that you *format the disk* and *let the installer create the partitions for you*.  I also suggested how you should edit your question and provide more details, so we can better understand your issue.  If you want help with this, you should engage with what others have suggested, otherwise you're not going to make much progress.